# Unavailable Folders key in registry - HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders

Tags: .net, windows, windows-installer, registry

I have .NET installer from 2010, which by default creates (or at least reliably created in 2010) multiple values in

**`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders`**

There is third side application which rely on that values in the key.

I just found, that the values are not created on every machine with Windows 10 where is the installation proceed . Actually, there is no Folders key in the registry at all.

The question is, why there isn't the Folder key on every machine, thus the required values, and what is the purpose of this Folder key?

Based on the values in the key (when available , probably every installed application has its values here) I originally thought (as majority on forums) that it contains information about what folders of the application should be deleted during uninstallation. But after testing I found that the values data does not correspond with the remainders after uninstallation.

Answer (score 0):

This registry key is part of the Windows Installer registry database. It is essentially an implementation detail, and shouldn't be used for anything as far as I am concerned. It lists or tracks all folders registered with Windows Installer.

On systems that have a lot of MSI packages installed it can take quite a while to read this key, so that might be why you didn't see any entries on some systems. I am not aware of any policies that can redirect this key. I suppose you could check the 32-bit equivalent on those systems if the key is really empty?

- 64-bit: **`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders`**
- 32-bit: **`HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders`**

That will have to do for now, will look back tomorrow.